# Cannot seem to force the caption to be on top of the table environement

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, captions, overlays, xltabular

I have a defined a `NiceTabular` which is later on overlayered by tikz to be eventually inserted in a table environment. The MWE is presented below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c}[name=R]
    \hline
    F & R1  & R2 & R3\\
    \hline
    40  & 2.033 & 2.033 & 2.033 \\
    1e3 & 2.033 & 2.033 & 2.034 \\
    1e4 & 2.036 & 2.070 & 2.179 \\
    1e5 & 3.700 & 3.738 & 5.756 \\
    1e6 & 10.31 & 11.40 & 21.57 \\
    1e7 & 31.14 & 38.17 & 78.99 \\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Comparing values.}
    \label{tab:compareR}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[orange,very thick,dashed](R-2-2.north west) -| (R-2-3.north east)-- (R-7-3.south east)-|(R-7-2.south west)--(R-2-2.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to force the caption to be on top of the tabular. Actually once inserted in my document, the caption is in page (n-1) - text inserted- then table in page (n)...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you wrote it, the `NiceTabular` has nothing to do with the `table` environment. It will placed where it is written. Place the `NiceTabular` inside the `table` environment and it will float with it (with the caption in relation to the `NiceTabular`).

Comment: why have you placed the (Nice)Tabular at a fixed point in the main document flow but the caption and tikz in a float to appear at a different point in the document? How do you intend that to appear?  I would place the tabular under the caption, in the float

Comment: My bad! Thank you @Qrrbrbirlbel

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments and answers, the `{NiceTabular}` should be put in the `{table}`. I post this answer to show how to simplify the Tikz code (a Tikz instruction with `rectangle` is enough).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparing values.}
\label{tab:compareR}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c}
    \hline
    F & R1  & R2 & R3\\
    \hline
    40  & 2.033 & 2.033 & 2.033 \\
    1e3 & 2.033 & 2.033 & 2.034 \\
    1e4 & 2.036 & 2.070 & 2.179 \\
    1e5 & 3.700 & 3.738 & 5.756 \\
    1e6 & 10.31 & 11.40 & 21.57 \\
    1e7 & 31.14 & 38.17 & 78.99 \\
    \hline
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [orange,very thick,dashed]
        (2-2.north west) rectangle (7-3.south east) ;
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

As @Qrrbrbirlbel has already pointed out in a comment, you need to place the `NiceTabular` environment *inside* the `table` environment -- and *after* the `\caption` statement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparing values.}
\label{tab:compareR}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c}[name=R]
    \hline
    F & R1  & R2 & R3\\
    \hline
    40  & 2.033 & 2.033 & 2.033 \\
    1e3 & 2.033 & 2.033 & 2.034 \\
    1e4 & 2.036 & 2.070 & 2.179 \\
    1e5 & 3.700 & 3.738 & 5.756 \\
    1e6 & 10.31 & 11.40 & 21.57 \\
    1e7 & 31.14 & 38.17 & 78.99 \\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[orange,very thick,dashed]
    (R-2-2.north west) -| 
    (R-2-3.north east)-- 
    (R-7-3.south east)-|
    (R-7-2.south west)--
    (R-2-2.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Done. Thank you!